# differentiability of a function $f:R^n \rightarrow R $

Tags: real-analysis

I have this function $f(x)= ||x||(1-e^\frac{-||x||^2}{|x_1|})$ if $x_1 \ne 0$, and null if $x_1=0$

I want to prove differentiability in the origin.
If I use the definition:
$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{||h||(1-e^\frac{-||h||^2}{|h_1|})}{||h||}$  must be null but if i consider $h=(h_1,0,....,0)$ the limit is equal to $1-e$ so i haven't differentiability?

Comment: Where did the $y$ come from?

Comment: The definition of differentiability from $\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ at $x$ is that *there exists a vector $D$* such that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\left\|f(x + h) - f(x) -  D\cdot h\right\|}{\|h\|} = 0$$ We know in your case that $f(0) = 0$, but what makes you think that the derivative $D$ is also $0$?

Comment: I've calculated partial derivatives and are null

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\tag 1 \frac{f(x_1,0,\dots,0)-f(0,\dots, 0)}{x_1} =\frac{|x_1|(1- e^{-1/|x_1|})}{x_1}.$$

As $x_1 \to 0^+,$ $(1)\to 1.$ As $x_1 \to 0^-,$ $(1)\to -1.$ Thus $\partial f/\partial x_1(0,\dots, 0)$ fails to exist. That implies $f$ is not differentiable at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

$D_v f(0)=\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(0+tv)-f(0)}{t}=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{|t|}{t} (1-e^\frac{t^2}{|tv_1|})$ is null for $v_1\ne 0$?

Comment: No, as I showed below the limit doesn't exist.